# Swift - What is a better alternative to Global Variables?

Tags: ios, swift, oop, swiftui, global-variables

### Context

Hi there,
I like using global variables to call managers or services to handle certain code.
But I am getting code smells in my code analyser (SonarQube).

### Question

Is there a big difference between form A and B? Or should I not be using either at all?
I prefer form A, but I'd like to avoid / suppress / resolve code smells.

### Form A

Some examples, what I prefer:

```
app.logout()
cameraManager.doSomething()
userDefaults.set(.example, true)
analytics.logEvent(.clicked_button)
popupManager.showPopup(message: "Hello world!")
```

The above can be achieved with:

```
var app = Global()

class Global {

}
```

### Form B

An alternative would be:

```
class Global {
    private init() {}
    public static let app = Global()
}
```

The usage would then change to `Global.app.logout()`

### Code Smells

[image: Code smells say difficult to use because of the risk of name classes, difficult to track bugs, updated from anywhere, difficult to properly test classes]

I partially agree with these points, but wouldn't the same count for Form B?
If so, is there better approach other than what I've shown above?

I'd love to hear your insights!

Comment: You may also want to post this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swift

Comment: You should always try to avoid global variables. First learn how to use Singletons and then learn how to use dependency injection instead.

Comment: Thanks @emrepun, looks interesting, will check it out later!

Comment: @nicksamo would you recommend using EnvironmentObject instead of all singleton usages if we're talking about SwiftUI? Quick source: https://mokacoding.com/blog/swiftui-dependency-injection/ Or do you feel Singletons (not Global Variables) still have their place?

Comment: Make a `class App { static func logout() { ... } }` so you can use it as `App.logout()`. No singleton (at least no public one, internally App can still work as singleton if needed), no globals.

Comment: Hi Kiril, that's great advice, unfortunately I also have singletons that need to store data. Like a CMS (Content Management System) Singleton that holds all of our localized texts (retrieved online). In a lot of scenarios it also seems messy to make many functions and variables static instead of just the class itself.

Comment: Lex, in such case static functions should only be a syntactic sugar to a private singleton. E.g. internally in `CMS` you have a singleton, and a proper instance functions. But you also can have extension with static functions to call `CMS.something()`

Comment: @LexBrouwers for standard objects that will be fetching / managing data, your best bet is to try to avoid Singletons. This way you can manage the exact instance of your class rather than one shared object across your app. In SwiftUI, you can use a class with an ObservedObject (or EnvironmentObject) to manage the code (the link you provided is a great start). Singletons are great because they are easy to use and you don't have to track where they initiated from across your app - so it's a good starting place - but they have downfalls that you'll figure out down the road.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'll look further into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that global variables, in and of themselves, are often considered a code smell.

Essentially, you are saying "I like `<code smell>` but my code analyzer is flagging it as a code smell."

Have you considered making your manager objects singletons? Consider the pattern Apple uses for things like `UserDefaults` (a class var `standard` that returns the shared `UserDefaults` object.)

### Edit:

Rereading your question, I guess that's what you are suggesting in form B. That makes the static var a class variable of the class, and turns the object into a singleton. It's not quite the same thing as a global.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Duncan! And also for double checking my question! Could you elaborate on what you feel are the main differences between Global Variables and Singletons? My colleague pointed me to this useful video https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift.  But I'd like to hear your opinion as well! Additionally, I'd like using dependency injection instead, but I'm not confident on using that in class- or struct extensions. In SwiftUI I'd lean towards using EnvironmentObject, but this might bring a lot of unnecessary complexity, what are your thoughts?

Comment: Also, do you have a suggestion for an appropriate name that I could use everywhere? I'm leaning towards ".instance", but there's also ".shared" and ".standard". I tried to make an extension to have my classes inherit a "Singleton" struct / class so that I don't have to write extra boilerplate code, but I had some trouble doing that too.

Comment: Global variables and singletons are both things you should avoid were possible. If you do need them, I think the naming of the singleton property is up to you. I rather like `.shared`, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: Thank you Duncan, I've accepted your answer for now! I'll look further into Singletons and Dependency Injection from here on out.